# JTextPane keeps throwing BadLocation

Tags: java, swing, syntax-highlighting, jtextpane

I have a JFrame that contains a JTextPane. The purpose of this JTextPane is to highlight words as I type them, something along the lines of a programmer's text editor. To accomplish this, I extended JTextPane, I implemented the **KeyListener** interface, and I had it setup as a **key listener** to self. The method that does some important work is **keyReleased**. The problem is, I can highlight the first word I type, but after that, I keep getting BadLocation, even though the **start** and the **end** are within document limits. I am posting some of my code snippets :

```
// this is my highlight method
private void highlight(int start,int end) throws BadLocationException {
      Document doc = getDocument();
      Color c = Color.red;
      String text = doc.getText(start,end);
      StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
      AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, c);
      setCharacterAttributes(aset, true);
      setSelectionStart(start);
      setSelectionEnd(end);
      replaceSelection(text);
}

//this is my keyReleased method
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        char character = arg0.getKeyChar();
        if(wordStarted) { // have I started typing a new word ?
            if(character == ' ') { // end word
                try {
                    int dot = getCaret().getDot();
                    highlight(wordStart, dot - 1);
                    setCaretPosition(dot);
                    wordStarted = false;
                } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if(Character.isLetter(character)) {
                wordStarted = true;
                wordStart = getCaret().getDot() -1;
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to type in : **public static** but only **public** is colored red. I even added some println statements for debugging, and this is the output:

```
this is outputted after writing public
Start param:0
End param:6
Document Length:7
Document START:0
Document END:8
text:public

this is outputted after writing static
Start param:7
End param:13
Document Length:14
Document START:0
Document END:15
text:public static 
javax.swing.text.BadLocationException: Invalid location
        at javax.swing.text.GapContent.getChars(GapContent.java:189)
        at javax.swing.text.GapContent.getString(GapContent.java:167)
        at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.getText(AbstractDocument.java:774)
        at ifirst.visual.CodePanel.highlight(CodePanel.java:49)
        at ifirst.visual.CodePanel.keyReleased(CodePanel.java:82)
        at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6069)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2810)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5885)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2105)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4469)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2163)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4295)
        at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1881)
        at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:742)
        at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1007)
        at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:879)
        at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:706)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4339)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2163)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4295)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:604)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:275)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:200)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:190)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:185)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:177)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
```

I am writing this code to get a hang of JTextPane. I am not interested in something like **JTextPane**.

Comment: Is there something missing from your code? I can't see anywhere that BadLocationException is being thrown from.  I think we need to see where your "text" variable is coming from in the replaceSelection call as it looks like it's coming from doc.getText(...) but theres no call to that

Comment: I forgot the line: String text = doc.getText(start,end);

Comment: I think I figured it out. The end param sent to the method the second time it's called is 13, and I think it specifies 13 characters from the character at position 7,and since it doesn't exist, the exception gets thrown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you discovered, the[Document.getText()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html#getText(int,%20int)) takes a start and *length*, not a start and *end* argument.  I thought I'd provide an answer and a link to the JavaDoc for others reading your question who might not look in the comments.

Comment: This was pretty annoying. 2 hours of debugging can save 10 minutes of reading,right? :)

Comment: Definitely true.  And the libraries are sometimes inconsistent, causing the need to check the javadocs, as half of the libraries use start,end+1 and the other half uses start,length.  Feh!